# Why isn't my elif statment working?

Tags: python, if-statement

Im new to python and im currently doing a practise sac for IT and im trying to get the program to read the first digit of the postcode and then set the number to the billing variable. When i run it, it just sets it as the first if statement even though the first number is not a 0 or a 6. Please help me out!!!![enter image description here][1]

```js
#commision = 1.125 For later on
#bid = 100 part of prac sac
total_cost = str(0)
billing = 0

for i in range(100000):
    postcode = input("What is your postcode?: \n")
    if len(postcode) == 4:
        break
    else:
        print("Postcode invalid. Please retype postcode.")
        continue

print(postcode)
print(postcode[0])

# This is where im having trouble
if (postcode[0]) == str(0) or str(0):
    billing = 25

elif (postcode[0]) == str(1) or str(2) or str(5):
    billing = 15

elif (postcode[0]) == str(3):
    billing = 12

else:
    billing = 20

print(billing)
```

Comment: you probably want to use `while True:` instead of the `for-loop`. The `continue` is unnecessary.

Comment: simply use a dictionary: `billing = {'0':25, '1':15, '2':15, '3':12, '5':15}.get(postcode[0], 20)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements are not working correctly because you are using the logical operators `and`, `or` in wrong manner, As these operators only compare two boolean values so you need to write `elif (postcode[0]) == str(1) or (postcode[0]) == str(2) or (postcode[0]) == str(5):` for each of the if statements, to compare two strings and return a boolean to apply these logical operators on.

```
if (postcode[0]) == "0" or (postcode[0]) == "6":
    billing = 25

elif (postcode[0]) == "1" or (postcode[0]) == "2" or (postcode[0]) == "5":
    billing = 15

elif (postcode[0]) == "3":
    billing = 12

else:
    billing = 20
```